# how to restrict Eclipse Code Minings search to avoid JRE and Dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse

The **Eclipse 2018-12** (4.10) added [Code Minings support in Java editor](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/jdt.php#jdt-codemining) which is supercool feature generating pseudo-line above the type/field/method with reference count and after click it perform search to show those references in Search tab.

The problem is that this counts also stuff from JRE and Dependencies, so with specific field

```
private ShipmentRepository shipmentRepository;
```

there is only 1 reference found (it's in my code), but for more generic method

```
public void add(Shipment shipment)
```

it founds 67 references (with 66 in spring and tomcat dependent jars and only 1 in my project code).

I am only interested in that 1 reference in my code, but I am not able **to restrict Code Minings search to ignore JRE and Dependencies**.

Any ideas how to limit the search?

Comment: You might report this as a feature request [here](https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining).

Comment: opened as https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining/issues/97

Comment: https://github.com/angelozerr/jdt-codemining/issues/97 got kindly redirected to Eclipse Bugzilla (Creating account in Eclipse Bugzilla is quite adventurous experience) so here it is https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=545661

Comment: Sorry for pointing you in the wrong direction. As far as I know new Eclipse accounts will be verified/activated manually after SPAM attacks have occurred.